# Measure Delay in android application

Tags: android

I create a voice transmission application to transmit voice in android Smartphone and I want to measure delay ,latency , etc.
and in order to do that the two devices should be synchronised  but i can not synchronise the two devices to display the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "I can not synchronise the two devices to display the same time" you mean that you're not allowed to change the clock on the device. That is correct.

What you could do is give your application an internal clock that synchronizes you synchronize (for example with ntp). When you want to measure something you read the time from this clock.

Comment: thanks for replay i use clocksyn application that synchronize the time with ntp server but after i synchronize the two device i continue to get delay (an offset between the ntp clock and the device clock ) and i have no idea why this happening